# Managing DB Links inside a view Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: database, view, plsql, union, dblink

Lets say you have six oracle database servers which are basically identical, but represent different factories.

For easier reporting, we could make a nice big view on a seventh server that selects in via @dblink1-6.  Works fine 99% of the time.  Someone kicks the cord at plant 5, your view is dead for all plants.  In this case, we want to just show the five that are working.

I cannot push the data from the six servers into the 7th, the 7th has to look out to 1-6.  We can't use a materialized view because that's not live data in this case... often it could be, but not with linked servers where the outside server can't push data in.

What can I write into a view that basically says if this dblink works, union in a select statement otherwise don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found, a view queries across a dblink will be marked invalid the first time it is accessed after a dblink is inaccessible.

My preferred solution would be to use materialized views so that the seventh server would always have access to at least some data - but in your case, you'd prefer to have no data rather than non-live data, so that's not an option.

In which case you need something to catch the "dblink inaccessible" exception and hide it from the view. The only way I can think of to solve that one is to query the tables using a pipelined function, which would swallow the exception and return zero rows if the dblink is down. Your original view would then UNION ALL the queries across six pipelined functions. Unfortunately I'm pretty sure this solution would perform very poorly in comparison with your original view, because it will not be able to do things like pushing predicates into the view (effectively the pipelined function will force the equivalent of a FTS across every dblink that's available, every time the query is run). Since your purpose is reporting, this may or may not be a big issue.

Note: I've never actually done this, so this answer is just "an idea to try".

Comment: The function idea is pretty creative.  That might be useful to me someday in the future, and I would never have thought of that.  The functions would be, as you say, very slow... looks like we're going to have slow data no matter what though.  If I was going to pick my method of slowing the data down, the materialized view would beat the function any day... as you said.   So I think that's a done decision, thanks for you help.

Comment: Figured I'd give an update on this...  ended up going with the function but combined it with a global temp table.  Whether through the function, or with straight up six db links with a big union statement, report performance was (predictably?) terrible when more than one plant's data was used.  Resolution: used the pipelined function to populate a global temp table, and then report off of that.  It works very fast (by our standards) and we've been having trouble with one of the servers, and the pipelined function definitely saved our ass in the five other plants.  Thank you Jeffrey Kemp! -John

Comment: You know, if you're happy to store the results locally, why not use an MV after all? The step where you're populating the GT could just as easily refresh the materialized view(s). Just a thought :)